# Page permalinks are http but show up as https?

Tags: permalinks, https

My page permalinks are http

[image: permalink http]

> Settings -> Site & Home URL set to http://

but the links all go to `https://`
It seems all my page permalinks are being rendered as https.

I do not have any redirect rules in my `.htaccess` that are making this happen.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apps.abc.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /apps.abc.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm stumped, been at this for a little while and can't for the life of me figure it out. I know it's going to be something really dumb I did or didn't do, I'm hoping someone can point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

This basically hard-codes the WordPress options for `siteurl` and `home`, which will means WordPress will redirect all requests to those URLs.

This won't change any permalinks in any content that you have in your site -- to do this I'd recommend using a plugin like [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to search and replace the URLs for `https://` to `http://`